# ServiceControl remove pending upgrade version

Tags: nservicebus, nsb-servicecontrol

I need to update the *servicecontrol* under current version *3.6.4* and installed on server `windows2012r2`.

To do this I need to upgrade to *3.8.2* before installing the latest version *4*.

However, I had installed version *4.13* beforehand and the installation gives

```
Version upgrade incompatible, you must upgrade to 3.8.2 => 1) uninstall version 4.13.0
```

> The question is: How do I uninstall version *4.13* without impact the current version *3.6.4*?
> doesn't seem not possible via "*Programs and Features*"

Thanks in advance for help.

Tony

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ServiceControl Management` utility, which you can find in the start menu.

The UI changed somewhat between versions, but you should be able to press a wrench icon and remove an instance, without removing the database and logs. Also the queue won't be removed. So when installing the correct version **use the same instance name** and all should work again.

As always, it's recommended to create a backup of the database and possibly any messages in `error` and `audit` queue before doing all this. It should work, but with computers, you never know. :-)

Also, feel free to email Particular Software at support@particular.net for any additional questions.

Comment: Ok thanks, I wanted to avoid this way (remove/reinstall) but I don't think I will have a choice. And yes backup will be carefull  ;o)